# Multiple table with excluding join

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have three tables. Table1 has all records from table2 and table3 plus some extra records that are not in those two tables. I need to write a query that shows me the records that are  in table1 but neither in table2 nor in Table3.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some table content, and the queries that you have tried, and the expected result.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? I know it's a weird question because Oracle owns MySQL, but still one's called Oracle and one's called MySQL.

Comment: Table1 stores all mobile telephone numbers on the company's network, Table 2 has numbers of numbers that are partially registered while Table 3 has numbers that are fully registered. Now Table 2 and table3 are subsets of table 1. In short I am trying to get numbers in Table 1 that are neither partially registered nor fully registered.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
minus
select * from table2
minus
select * from table3
```

Comment: Okay buddy, let me try your code and see what happens